# Cloudformation stack stuck in UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS for a long period

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My CloudFormation stack is stuck on the following state: *UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS* for the past 4 HOURS.

During stack update the following deletion error happening: **"Deleting RestApi 8ji3xa85ai failed. Please remove all base path mappings related to the RestApi in your domains: mysubdomain.mydomain.com (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: f0c2358c-58ad-4b6f-a1e0-9e9b261165f0; Proxy: null)"**

This is not a nested stack and there is no nested stack linked to the main stack.

I removed the base paths mappings and custom domain manually but the stack still on the same state.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to unblock that state by using the following command:

`aws cloudformation continue-update-rollback --stack-name stackName`

After that stack failed rollback and I was able to delete it manually.